# SpriteKit game physics lagging

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

I have been working on a SpriteKit game for a while now and I have an annoying problem that I can't get rid of. I don't want to tell too much about the game, but it is very simple. I generate some objects (SKSpriteNodes) each second that are falling down from the top of the screen using SpriteKits physics and the player is interacting with them.

Most of the time the game runs perfectly (constant 60 FPS). The problem is that sometimes (maybe once per minute or something like that), the game starts to lag a little bit for about 3-5 seconds (still at 60 FPS) and then it runs perfectly again (note: i'm running the game on an iPhone 5s). It seems to be because of the physics, because if I add a normal move-action on an object, it runs very smoothly while the nodes affected by the physics are lagging.

I tried to remove some particles and effects that I have and I reuse my objects, but I can't remove the lag. I decided to create a very simple test project to see if the lag would be gone but it is still there. Here is the code:

```
#import "GameScene.h"

static const uint32_t groundCategory = 1 << 0;
static const uint32_t objectCategory = 1 << 1;

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    // Init
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, -3.2f);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    // Ground
    SKPhysicsBody* ground = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0, -88) toPoint:CGPointMake(self.size.width, -88)];
    ground.categoryBitMask = groundCategory;
    self.physicsBody = ground;

    // Start game loop
    SKAction* waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
    SKAction* sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(addObject) onTarget:self], waitAction]];
    SKAction* repeatAction = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
    [self runAction:repeatAction withKey:@"fallingObjectsAction"];
}

- (void)addObject
{
    SKSpriteNode* newObject = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(88, 88)];
    newObject.name = @"Object";
    newObject.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:newObject.size];
    newObject.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.size.height + newObject.size.height);
    newObject.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = objectCategory;
    newObject.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory;
    newObject.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

    [self addChild:newObject];
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    if ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"Object"])
        [contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
    else if ([contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"Object"])
        [contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];
}

@end
```

I generate one object each second and let it fall down from the top of the screen. When it hits the ground, it is removed.

Am I using the physics wrong or is it SpriteKit's fault that it is lagging? It seems strange, because I'm running a very simple project using an iPhone 5s with iOS 8.

Comment: How did you determine that the game is still running at 60 fps when it is lagging? Did you use the drawsFPS and other flags? What's the CPU usage (see Xcode Debug Navigator tab) when it lags and when it doesn't?

Comment: In the viewController, I have set skView.showsFPS = YES; The CPU usage is (for the test project that I posted the code for) 11% when it is not lagging and 11% when it is lagging, so no difference there.

Comment: sounds like the lag is something else, for instance if you try to move the physics-enabled nodes with move actions this will conflict with physics

Comment: I have no idea what it is. I tried to turn the gravity off and move the objects manually by changing their position in the update method and that works perfectly all the time. But I don't want to solve it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I've been having the same issue with physics. The issue was objects are jittery despite low CPU usage and a consistent FPS. I've finally figured out why. The solution I found is do not set physicsWorld.speed to 1.0; set it to a .9999. Now everything runs smoothly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was having jitter in my game even when the debugger read 60 fps and this solved my problem. I wonder if this is a bug on Apple's part? Either way, you saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: According to comment in other thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011362/spritekit-choppy-movement-even-with-60fps-on-device) SpriteKit physics engine calculations are always tied to the frame-rate which means that you might see some lagging here and there randomly in a constant movement even if there is a really minimal fps drop so unfortunately right now there seem to be no 100% working way to fix this perfectly if you are using spritekit's physics engine. Best thing you can do is to optimize your update method as much as you can or do not use spritekit's physics engine at all.