# SpriteKit: Choppy Movement even with 60fps on device

Tags: objective-c, animation, sprite-kit, sprite

I am making an infinite scroller game and I spawn sprites in `update()` function based on the counter like so:

```
-(void)update {

_spawnCar += 1;

if (_spawnCar>=500) {
  _spawnCar = 0;
  [self spawnCar];
}
```

Inside `spawnCar` I add the sprite to self and apply Impulse to it once. This code is just a sample, actual code has more spawns, like spawning trees, roads, etc.

I have about 50 sprites at normal play. On device it gives perfect 60fps. But what I don't get is the movement of the car sometimes are jerky/stutter/choppy.

I have no idea what is causing the stutter because I do not update the car position in the update. I just applied impulse once and that's it. Any idea how to check the source of this choppiness movement.

I use `SKCameraNode` to center on hero character and hero character walks in one direction.

Comment: You might have some game logic that is causing the stuttering at such small intervals that the fps meter doesn't detect. There are many ways to debug this but a quick and easy solution (assuming your game is simple) is to remove game logic until your issue is fixed which can help you identify the bottleneck in your code. It could be running too much logic in the update method, could be instantiating nodes instead of pooling them etc.

Comment: However it is important to note, Sprite Kit does not use a fixed time-step for its physics calculations, which means all physics are tied to the frame-rate. This means that if you REALLY pay close attention to your moving bodies, you may notice slight stuttering here and there. This is the nature of of variable time-step physics engines. Maybe in the future Apple will give an option for choosing. But if your stutter is clearly noticeable and is consistent then it's definitely a performance issue with you code. You should also post your number of draw calls.

Comment: What do you mean by "instantiating nodes instead of pooling them etc"?

Comment: Instead of initializing nodes as the game runs which can be expensive because you need to allocate the node and its texture data and add it to the node tree, you can have an array of nodes that already exist and reuse them. The greatest bottleneck will come from allocating the SKTexture which involves searching for the texture, reading it from disk and loading it into memory. So if you don't want to pool nodes at least make sure to re-use SKTextures (I.e Initialize all SKTextures beforehand and re-use them).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll try that soon.

Comment: Epic Byte, can you recommend a framework that does not tie physics calculations to frame rate?